# Thinking Sphinx without condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx, will-paginate

I have a following model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  define_index do
    indexes content
    indexes :name, sortable: true
    has type
  end
end
```

and special type of an article is:

```
class About < Article
end
```

and the same for `Contact`

I would like to have searchable articles index action without articles with type of "About" or "Contact"

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @articles = Article.search(params[:search],
                               :with_all => {:type => nil},
                               :page => params[:page],
                               :per_page => 10)
  end
end
```

But the `@articles` instance variable contains everytime also "About" & "Contact" articles.

This is very strange (seems like will_paginate messing everything up):

```
@articles = Article.search(
  :without =>  {:type => %w(About Contact)}).include?(About.first) # false

@articles = Article.search(
  :without =>  {:type => %w(About Contact)},
  :page => 1,
  :per_page => 1000).include?(About.first) # true
```

=============================================================================

Finally I did:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  define_index do
    indexes content
    indexes :name, sortable: true

    has "CRC32(type)", :as => :article_type, :type => :integer
  end
end
```

and:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
     @articles = Article.search(params[:search],
                               :without =>  {:article_type => ["About".to_crc32, "Contact".to_crc32]},
                               :page => params[:page],
                               :per_page => 10)
  end
end
```

and it works. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Thinking Sphinx FAQ](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html):

> **Filtering on String Attributes**
>
> While you can have string columns as
>   attributes in Sphinx, they aren’t stored as strings. Instead, Sphinx
>   figures out the alphabetical order, and gives each string an integer
>   value to make them useful for sorting. However, this means it’s close
>   to impossible to filter on these attributes.
>
> So, to get around this, there’s two options: firstly, use integer
>   attributes instead, if you possibly can. This works for small result
>   sets (for example: gender). Otherwise, you might want to consider
>   manually converting the string to a CRC integer value:
>
> `has "CRC32(category)", :as => :category, :type => :integer`
>
> This way, you can filter on it like so:
>
> `Article.search 'pancakes', :with => {   :category => 'Ruby'.to_crc32 }`
>
> Of course, this isn’t amazingly clean, but it will work quite well.
>   You should also take note that CRC32 encoding can have collisions, so
>   it’s not the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude About & Contact type from conditions like -

```
@articles = Article.search(params[:search],
             :without => {:type => %w(About Contact)},
             :page => params[:page],
             :per_page => 10)
```

OR

I am not very sure on below but you can give it try..

```
  define_index do
    indexes content
    indexes :name, sortable: true
    indexes(:type), :as => :article_type
  end

    @articles = Article.search(params[:search],
                 :without => {:article_type => %w(About Contact)},
                 :page => params[:page],
                 :per_page => 10)
```

Also, make sure inside your database records you have type attribute got inserted properly..

Comment: I tried this one, but I still get articles with type of Contact and Article as a result

Comment: @articles = Article.search(
      :without =>  {:type => %w(About Contact)},
      :page => 1,
      :per_page => 1000).include?(About.first) #=> true

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use "with" instead of "with_all"? For example:

```
@articles = Article.search(params[:search],
                               :with => {:type => nil},
                               :page => params[:page],
                               :per_page => 10)
```

Comment: In this case I get: searchd error (status: 1): invalid or truncated request